# how to return total sold p / year for several years in columnar format?

Tags: sql

The SQL below give me the columns for Account, Name and the Total Sale for the year of 2015.But how, if possible, can I add another column for the previous year of 2014 ?

```
select  a.AcctNo, b.Name, Sum(a.TotSold) as [ Total Sold ]  
from Orders as A
Join Accounts as b on a.AcctNo = b.AcctNo
where (a.PurchaseDate between   '1/1/2015' and '12/31/2015'  )
Group by a.AcctNo, b.Name
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are actually using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select o.AcctNo, a.Name,
       Sum(case when year(PurchaseDate) = 2015 then TotSold else 0 end) as tot_2015,
       Sum(case when year(PurchaseDate) = 2014 then TotSold else 0 end) as tot_2014
from Orders o Join
     Accounts a
     on a.AcctNo = o.AcctNo
where PurchaseDate >= '2014-01-01' 
      PurchaseDate < '2016-01-01' 
Group by o.AcctNo, a.Name ;
```

Notes:

- Use ISO standard formats for date constants.
- When using dates, try not to use `between`.  It doesn't work as expected when there is a time component.  The above inequalities work regardless of a time component.
- Use table aliases that are abbreviations of the table name.  That makes the query easier to follow.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer and the notes. Very useful.

Comment: Nitpicking: `'2014-01-01'` is not a SQL standard date literal `DATE '2015-01-01'` would be.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . That is the *ANSI* standard for SQL.  ISO has two standards for dates (hey, if one is good, two are better, right?)  The YYYY-MM-DD format is ISO 8601 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).  Most databases understand it; Oracle needs the "date" hint.  And SQL Server (and perhaps others) can get confused by arcane internationalization settings.  But, it works pretty well.  And, SAS doesn't understand it.